# How to use the cancel function in redux "timeoutScheduler" middleware docs example?

Tags: redux, middleware

When I implement the MW it works great but how do I invoke the "cancel" function
if I want to clear the timeout?
Here's is the code:([taken from Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#seven-examples))

```
   /**
 * Schedules actions with { meta: { delay: N } } to be delayed by N milliseconds.
 * Makes `dispatch` return a function to cancel the timeout in this case.
 */
const timeoutScheduler = store => next => action => {
  if (!action.meta || !action.meta.delay) {
    return next(action)
  }
​
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(
    () => next(action),
    action.meta.delay
  )
​
  return function cancel() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes `dispatch` return a function to cancel the timeout in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the other middleware in the chain correctly do `return next(action)`, then your call to `dispatch()` would return this `cancel` function.  For example:

```
const cancel = store.dispatch({type : "INCREMENT", meta : {delay : 1000}});

// kill it off
cancel();
```

Or, similarly with a bound action creator in a React component:

```
// assume we have an action creator like this passed to connect():
function incrementWithDelay() {
    return {type : "INCREMENT", meta : {delay : 1000}};
}


const cancel = this.props.incrementWithDelay();
cancel();
```